# Why does my edit/update route break?

Tags: python, flask

I am creating a very simple application using the Flask framework. I'm going along smoothly until I create an edit/update route for an Employee model. What I want to do is to have an employee update their information and when they hit submit, sql_alchemy does its magic. The problem that I am experiencing is that my edit url is breaking where it was working before hand. I've been poking at my app but I can't seem to get it to work.This is the relevant code for my edit/update action:

```
    @app.route('/edit_employee/<id>', methods=['GET','PUT'])
    def edit_employee(id):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        employee = Employee.query.get(id)
        return render_template('edit.html', employee=employee)
    else:
        existing_employee = Employee.query.get(id)
        updated_employee = Employee(request.form['name'], request.form['title'],
                            request.form['email'], request.form['department'])
        file = request.files['profile_image']
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            filename = updated_employee.name
            # Destroy the old image first
            os.remove(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        existing_employee = updated_employee
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('all_employees'))
```

Here is a layout.html file. I suspect the problem is located in my form_action block but I am not sure. I'm only pasting a portion of my html view (It's essentially a form with attributes).

```
<body> 
<div>
  <form{% block form_action %}{% endblock %}>
    <h2>{% block h2 %}{% endblock %}</h2>
    <div class="control-group">
      <div class="controls">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name"
          placeholder="Specify name" value="{{ request.form.name }}"
          required>
          .............
```

My edit view:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block h2 %}Edit a Blackduck employee{% endblock %}
{% block form_action %}action="{{ url_for('edit_employee') }}" enctype=multipart/form-data method=post class="form-horizontal"{% endblock %}
{% block submit %}Update{% endblock %}
```

I've been working with Rails and Sinatra for a while now and I am simply not used to Flask's error rendering. For this error `BuildError: ('edit_employee', {}, None)` I can't tell exactly what line is the problem unlike Rails. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your `edit_employee` function takes an argument named `id` but you aren't passing any argument when you call `url_for`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is saying that you are trying to access a route called `edit_employee` with zero arguments, but such a route does not exist. Your `edit_employee` route accepts an `<id>` parameter, so you need to call the route like this:

`{{ url_for('edit_employee', id = id) }}`

Comment: Oh is that what it was? I did url_for('edit_employee/<id>'). Thanks for pointing that out. Btw as a bonus do you know any libraries that highlight better errors. I'm sure I'll get use to the Flask way of things but I was just wondering. Thanks.